# Printing two arrays with one loop

Tags: php

I want to print two different arrays with different values with one loop.

I already tried this but it is not working:

```
    $a=array('a','s','d');
    $b=array('z','x','c','v');

    foreach(($a as $c) && ($b as $bb)){
        echo $c.$bb;
    }
```

Comment: You're using the and logical operator!

Comment: What results are you trying to get?  `a s d z x c v` or `a z s x d c null v`? Or something else?

Comment: jermy i want to print a z s x d c v

Comment: @Amit Maurya pls accept answers if it is useful to u

Answer (score 2):

assuming array might be different length, and iterate with most index count.

```
$a=array('a','s','d');
$b=array('z','x','c','v');

// iterate with most index count
$cnt = max(count($a), count($b));

for($i=0 ; $i < $cnt ; $i++) {
  // check array $a
  if(isset($a[$i]))
     echo $a[$i];

  // if may print separator here

  // check array $b
  iF(isset($b[$i]))
     echo $b[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about v?

```
<?php
$a = array('a','s','d');
$b = array('z','x','c','v');

function iter($a, $b) {
 return $a.$b;
};

echo implode(array_map("iter", $a, $b));

// Or use a closure PHP 5.3
echo implode(array_map(function($a, $b){ return $a.$b;}, $a, $b));
```